# How would I write a line of code to see if the vertices of a path has been visited?

Tags: algorithm, scala, data-structures, breadth-first-search

How would I correctly write "Mark all the vertices as not visited" in scala code?
I've seen that in Java it can be written as `boolean visited[] = new boolean[V]` but what about scala?

Code Source: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-if-there-is-a-path-between-two-vertices-in-a-given-graph/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only works if the vertices are indexed with 0, 1, ..., V-1.
You can also maintain a [set](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/sets.html) so you can have arbitrary IDs for your vertices. The methods of adding, removing and checking all run in constant time.

Comment: Yah I've actually switched over to a set now but for some reason my code always producing false

Comment: I'd need to see more to help you. Try to start a new project and look if you get a set working there in an easiert context, to make sure youre using its API properly. It often helps to have such an indipendent testing area.

Comment: Yah I'm doing it on my own IDE and it seems I was missing an if statement after my otter while loop completed to check if my set contains the second node nows all good. (code is based off of that Java one)

Comment: Remember to use the debugger for such cases instead of printing out values. This speeds up your workflow if you get stuck.